# Android RatingBar doesn't accept float values

Tags: android, floating-point, ratingbar

I have an android rating bar in my app, and it only displays int ratings.

For example:

```
float ratingValue = 1.5f;
myRatingBar.setRating(ratingValue);
```

and the ratingbar displays 2 full stars. How can I make it display one and a half stars, or two and a half?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to use

```
float ratingValue = 1.5f;
myRatingBar.setRating(ratingValue); // to set rating value
myRatingBar.setStepSize(ratingValue);// to show to stars
```

public void setStepSize (float stepSize)

Sets the step size (granularity) of this rating bar.
 Parameters

stepSize  The step size of this rating bar. For example, if half-star granularity is wanted, this would be 0.5.

Comment: I think you mean `myRatingBar.setStepSize(0.5f);`

Answer (score 2):

add `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"` to your xml

Comment: why do I have to use this style? It does not fit my needs. Why the rating cannot be changed when I use my own style?

Answer (score 0):

the solution that have worked for me was setting the step size **before** setting the rating value :
`float ratingValue = 3.5f;
myRatingBar.setStepSize(0.5f);
myRatingBar.setRating(ratingValue);`