# Indicate "no ratings yet" in Android Ratingbar

Tags: android, user-interface, ratingbar

What is the intended way to show the user that nobody has rated yet with a Ratingbar?

If I use zero stars as not rated then there is no difference to a bad rated item.

If I use 2.5 Stars then it looks like an average item.

If I color it grey then it looks like it is deactivated.

Comment: `If I use zero stars as not rated then there is no difference to a bad rated item` **False**. 0 stars is "not rated". 0.5 star is "really very bad".

Comment: You are right. I just checked the behaviour in the google play apps. But it starts at 1 Star.

Comment: Google can what they want. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7338904/2649012.

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't give the rating, you can hide the rating bar and show the rating bar where the user gives the rating according to the user's rating.

Comment: If you hide the RatingBar, how can the user rate anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Inside of the RatingBar function put this line of code in your Java source code (be sure to add the correct imports too):

```
RatingBar mRatingBars = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.mRatingBars);
if(mRatingBars.getRating().equals(0)){
     TextEdit textE = (TextEdit) findViewById(R.id.textE);
     textE.setText("No Rating Found");
}
```

This will allow you to show that there are no ratings present.

But, you can also have to create an invisible TextEdit, like this:

```
TextEdit:
    android:id="@+id/textE"
    android:text=""
```

Also in your XML where your RatingBar is, put

```
android:id="@+id/mRatingBars"
```