# Android Rating Bar shows only full stars, not half stars too

Tags: android, ratingbar

I'm using rating bars in my Android application. But it only shows full stars, when I also want half stars.

I inserted a SQLite row with a name and the ratingValue, in there the ratingValue stands as "3.5" but my application turns it into "4". Even if my StepSize is "0.5", even the default value is changed to "3"

**EDIT:**
If you click on the listrow, it dialogs another ratingbar which you can "rate" and if you click on a button, it sends the rating value into the database. The listitem RatingBar is only for showing the "average" rating but that's where it goes wrong, it rounds the value up

**EDIT 2:**
set the stepsize to 0.1 and now, strangely, only the middle star accepts the float number...
The rest of the stars are still only full 
And if i set rating on 1.2, only the second star accepts float value, 0.2 the first, etc but the other stars (not in that range) are only or full or empty

Here's some code

**ListItem_layout**

```
<TableRow>    
    <RatingBar
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sportsRatingBar"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:rating="1.1"
        android:stepSize="0.1" />
```

**ListItem**

```
if(ratingBar!=null) {
                ratingBar.setRating(p.getRating());
                ratingBar.setTag(p.getId());
            }
```

**Reusable class**

```
public float getRating() { return Rating; }
```

**SQLite Table Column for rating**

```
 COLUMN_RATING + " real not null);"
```

**And last, getting from database**

```
c.getFloat(COLUMN_RATING_COL));
```

**some images to explain**
[image: after setting first ratingbar to 2.6]

Comment: I have found the answer, partly due to @Dave Ranjan and partly with adding a style to ratingbar, found here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/31307775/5985522

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you don't need any library for this, I just tried it, and it working.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:stepSize="0.1"
    android:rating="2.5"/>
```

I set value of start to 4.5 and it is working that way.

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.coloredRatingBar1);
    ratingBar.setRating(4.8f);
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onRatingChanged: rating : "+rating);
        }
    });
```

Comment: this doesn't help me, if i read the values from the database it says the right value, an float, but from the moment i want to display it into my ratingbar, it's rounded up

Comment: I tried to set rating dynamically like this `ratingBar.setRating(4.5f);` and it worked. Please try the same.

Comment: thanks for the help, i'm a bit further now (Editted in my question) but the value has to come from the sqlite database. and with the database, only the middle star "accepts" the float...

Comment: if you'd set <Ratingbar style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle" ... />, then it has fully helped me and i'll accept this helpfull answer then ;)

Answer (score 3):

First of all the the way rating widget is defined it cannot accept values. Clickable is set to false and isIndicator is made true. To accept input define the widget in the following way

```
<RatingBar
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sportsRatingBar"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:rating="2.5"
        android:stepSize="0.5" />
```

For the getting the values not sure about how the variable Rating is being set

Check out the image for how the widget looks [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqhOP.png)!

Comment: the RatingBars in the list may not be manually changed, so it has te be an indicator and the clickable is set to false so i can give an dialog box that pops up if you click on a listrow.

Comment: In that case your code was fine. If you could share the getRating code would be able to help you.

Comment: that would be the reusable class, it's just that method ;)

Comment: how is that value for the variable "Rating" getting set is the question. There could be an issue with that

Comment: i defined it as private float Rating = 2.5f

Comment: Thanks stepsize 0.5 was what I needed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's beacause in the XML you have

```
android:isIndicator="true"
```

If you remove the tag the problem is solved. But obviuosly you don't want the user to be able to change the rating. To avoid this you can set it in code

```
MaterialRatingBar ratingBar=view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
ratingBar.setIsIndicator(true);
ratingBar.setRating((float)myFloatValue);
```